# How to view localhost projects on Android SDK via hosts file [Froyo]

Tags: localhost, android-2.2-froyo

I have followed these steps for editing the hosts file in android sdk [froyo] :

- emulator -avd [android-machine] -partition-size 128
- adb remount
- adb push [path-to-edited-hosts-file] /system/etc/hosts

i've checked via:

- adb shell

and confirmed that it is edited properly with this content

127.0.0.1     localhost
10.0.2.2      myproject.local
10.0.2.2      anotherproject.local

i've also verified that http://10.0.2.2
accesses the localhost properly ( in this case, i
don't have the serveralias which my project needs )

but i still just can't access the myproject.local
from within the SDK